# An up to date version of the rflex / b21 stack

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a question. I have spent some time today fixing the issues of the atrvjr_node I have based on the b21_node (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rflex). The issue was with the wrong odometry output. And then I found that there is a newer version of the stack with some fixes. The newer stack can be cloned:
git clone http://code.in.tum.de/git/rwib21.git

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12992/an-up-to-date-version-of-the-rflex-/-b21-stack/) by [mmedvede](https://answers.ros.org/users/1773/mmedvede/) on ROS Answers with karma: 221 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-02-15**:
Do you want to merge them with the current rflex stack?

**Comment by [mmedvede](https://answers.ros.org/users/1773/mmedvede/) on 2012-06-06**:
David, merging following changes would improve the rflex driver and b21 node:
http://code.in.tum.de/indefero/index.php//p/rwib21/source/commit/a0c9fb6d90bc6cda9d1f0b8af046c0872fff5cb9/
http://code.in.tum.de/indefero/index.php//p/rwib21/source/commit/1f3c001df573698a7abec9a25b08df4ff6de9328/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Updated rflex driver package that includes atrvjr node is here: [http://www.cs.uml.edu/~mmedvede/files/rflex.tar.gz](http://www.cs.uml.edu/%7Emmedvede/files/rflex.tar.gz)
The only tested capability is motor control. Sonars and other features have not been tested for atrvjr. The package has some patches from the repository I have referenced in the question.

---

Originally posted by [mmedvede](https://answers.ros.org/users/1773/mmedvede/) with karma: 221 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2